# Spring Data JPA how to use sorting?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf, spring-boot

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/hotel")
class HotelController {

    @Autowired
    private HotelRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model, @PageableDefault(page = 0, value = 10) Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Hotel> page = repository.findAll(pageable);
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "hotel/list";
    }
}
```

My question: How to generate links to sort using the Page object on view layer with Thymeleaf template engine?

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you need to do? Please show some code that you have that is not working the way you expect it to

Comment: I want to create a table with sortable columns. How to generate links to sort using the Page object?

Comment: What you are describing is a multilayer problem. First you need to implement paging and sorting at the persistence layer. Check out the following tutorial. http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-six-sorting/. Then you need to come up with the controllers that will handle the request arguments from the browser and call the persistence layer

Comment: Paging and sorting is already there in persistence layer (cf `Page<Hotel>`). I guess you need to look at `@PageableDefault` and other Spring Data MVC features (read the manual maybe)?

Comment: How to use http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html in template to generate links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a th:href="@{~/admin/hotel(sort=(${page?.sort?.getOrderFor('title')?.ascending} ? 'title,desc' : 'title,asc'))}">title</a>
```