# How to get Sorting from Pageable to Thymeleaf link property?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I want to add pagination links to my document.

```
<a class="item"
    th:href="@{/works(
        page=${pageNum},
        size=${page.pageable.getPageSize()},
        sort=${page.pageable.sort})}"
    th:text="${pageNum}"
    th:classappend="${page.pageable.getPageNumber() eq pageNum} ? active"></a>
```

`page` is the [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) object holding the content and [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) object.

The problem is `sort=${page.pageable.sort}`. It creates "sort=title: ASC". But I need the format "sort=title,asc", as described in [this chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web) of Spring Data Docs. I assume there is a better way than building the needed string by myself. It is a common problem, I think.

What is the best way to create a usable sort parameter string?

I don't need a static behavior as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22939037/3898725)

- Spring 5
- Thymeleaf 3

Comment: We are now in spirng 6, and pageable api seams still suffer from this. Api for creating sort is great, but reading sort from an existing pageable is not that great

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Pageable` or a `Page` in your `Controller`, so you can access the `Sort` from it by calling its `getSort()` method. Knowing that `Sort` is `Iterable<Order>` you should be able to iterate over `Order` instances - each containing a pair of (property, direction) - and build an arbitrary `sort` string. Here's an example using Java 8 streams and lambdas, but it can be done imperatively of course:

```
String sort = page.getSort().stream()
    .map(order -> order.getProperty() + ":" + order.getDirection())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
model.addAttribute("sort", sort);
```

This example joins property and direction using `":"` and then joins all orders using `","`. According to your comment, you want to use `","` instead of `":"`, but that may lead you into other problems with parsing a list of `Order`.

You may want to see how `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` works, specifically its `parseParameterIntoSort` method to understand how the corresponding parsing logic works.